# Java File Iteration in For loop

Tags: java, file, for-loop

- I have few files saved in my local directory. One video file and one
  xml file. Video file details will be stored in xml file.

  - We are moving videos from one system to another system. Before
    uploading the video file and xml data from one system to another
    system, need to check for the title of video in the other system and 
    upload only if the same title doesn't exist.
  - This is working fine. But uploading is happening 4 times instead of 2
    times. Please help.

Here is the main code:

```
List<File> videoFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
        List<File> xmlFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
File[] allVideos = checkVideos();
        for(File file:allVideos ) {
            if(file.getName().endsWith("flv")) {
                videoFiles .add(file);
            }
            if(file.getName().endsWith("xml")) {
                xmlFiles .add(file);
            }   
        }

        System.out.println(videoFiles.size());
        System.out.println(xmlFiles.size());

        processUpload(videoFiles ,xmlFiles);
```

Here are the methods:

```
private static void processUpload(List<File> videoFiles, List<File> xmlFiles) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, ApiException {
    NodeList nodes = null;
    File video= null;
    File xml = null;
    String title = null;
    String localFileTitle = null;
    Media newMedia = null;
    for(int i=0;i < videoFiles.size();i++) {
        System.out.println("videoFiles.getName() ->"+videoFiles.get(i).getName());
        video= videoFiles.get(i);
        for(int j=0;j < xmlFiles.size();j++) {
            xml = xmlFiles.get(j);
            System.out.println("xmlFiles.getName() ->"+xmlFiles.get(i).getName());
                nodes = parseXml(xml);
                localFileTitle = processNodes(nodes);
                title = checkTitles(localFileTitle);
                newMedia = initiateUploadProcess(flv, title );
                }
            }
        }

private static NodeList parseXml(File xmlFile) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    //System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("video");
    return nList;
}

private static String processNodes(NodeList nodes) {
String fileTitle = null;
    if(nodes.getLength() >= 1) {
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nodes.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nodes.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
               Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
               fileTitle = eElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent();
               if(fileTitle != null) {
              //System.out.println("Local File Title ------>"+fileTitle);
               }
            }
        }
    }
    return fileTitle;
}

private static String checkTitles(String localTitle) throws ApiException {
    String title = null;
    MediaList mediaResponse = fetchVideos(caID);
    if(mediaResponse.totalCount >= 1) {
        for(MediaEntry media:mediaResponse.objects) {
            if(!localTitle.equals(media.name)) {
                System.out.println("Titles are not same. Need to return");
                title = localTitle;
                }
            }
        }
    return title ;
}

private static MediaEntry initiateUploadProcess(File videoFile,
        String localFileTitle) throws ApiException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    UploadToken ktoken = null;
    UploadMedia entry = null;
    MediaEntry mediaEntry = null;
    ktoken = generateToken();
    if (ktoken != null) {
        //System.out.println("ktoken.id ----------->" + ktoken.id);
        if (ktoken.id != null) {
            uploadToken(ktoken.id, flvFile);
            entry = uploadMediaToChannel(categoryID, categoryName, localFileTitle);
            if (entry.id != null) {
                System.out.println("entry.id ------->" + entry.id);
                mediaEntry = addMediaContent(ktoken.id, entry.id);
                }
            }
        }
    return mediaEntry;  
}
```

Here is the output:

```
videoFiles.getName() ->22701846_91167469.flv
xmlFiles.getName() ->22701846_91167469.xml
Titles are not same. Need to return
Titles are not same. Need to return
video.id ------->0_50wh1m4p
xmlFiles.getName() ->22701846_91167469.xml
Titles are not same. Need to return
Titles are not same. Need to return
video.id ------->0_79v605ue
videoFiles.getName() ->22701846_91477939.flv
xmlFiles.getName() ->22701846_91477939.xml
Titles are not same. Need to return
Titles are not same. Need to return
video.id ------->0_0kihent1
xmlFiles.getName() ->22701846_91477939.xml
Titles are not same. Need to return
Titles are not same. Need to return
Titles are not same. Need to return
video.id ------->0_miogft0i
```

Comment: This is 2016. Why don't you use the new file API?

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo-code, you have something like those two loops there:

```
for (i in 1,2)
  for (j in 1, 2)
    ... 
    upload
```

And you are surprised that you have 4 (2 x 2) uploads?

Try something like:

```
for (i in 1,2)
 ... fetch video file info
 ... fetch xml file info
 upload
```

instead!

Answer (score 0):

Doing the nested for loops is not very efficient, but I think the problem is in your checkVideos() method (not listed in the question) and it is returning duplicate file objects.

Edit: the line where you print the xml file is using the "i" variable (from the outer loop)

Comment: No I did print and see only 4 files are in this folder. 2 video and 2 xml files.